# Cerrar todos los formularios si se cierra el formulario de menu

Tags: c#, wpf

Mi pregunta es la siguiente: ¿cómo puedo hacer para cerrar todos los formularios wpf  de mi aplicación si se llega a cerrar el formulario wpf de menú?

gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Si vas a `App.xaml`, puedes añadir una propiedad llamada [`ShutdownMode`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.shutdownmode?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Tienes 3 posibles valores:

> OnMainWindowClose - Cuando se cierre la ventana principal
>
> OnExplicitShutdown - Debes definir un método ShutDown y llamarlo manualmente
>
> OnLastWindowClose - Cuando se cierre la última ventana de la app.  Esta es la opción por defecto.

Asi que en tu caso, lo que debes hacer es añadir `OnMainWindowClose`:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
         Startup="Application_Startup"
         ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose"
         >
```

**Edit**

En el caso que expones en tu comentario, tienes un par de opciones:

- Seguir con el `ShutdownMode` a `OnMainWindowClose`, y lo que debes hacer es, en el formulario de login, una vez crees el formulario principal, establecerlo como formulario principal con:

  ```
  VentanaMenu ventanaMenu= new VentanaMenu();
  Application.Current.MainWindow = ventanaMenu;
  ```
- Otra opción es que cambies el `ShutdownMode` a `OnExplicitShutdown`, y por ejemplo en el evento `Closing` de la ventana que quieres que al cerrarse se cierre la aplicación, llames a `ShutDown`:

  ```
  Application.Current.Shutdown();
  ```

Comment: Gracias por responder, Tengo una situacion, mi StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" es mi formulario de login, luego de ahi realiza la validacion y salta al formulario menu, si lo pongo ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose" en App.xaml, cuando valida mi formulario de login cierra todo, como puedo hacer?

Comment: @Andres revisa mi respuesta editada

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo soluciono de este modo:

Tengo un array estático (en una clase estática) de cuadros de diálogo (List)

```
private List<Window> _dialogos = new List<Window>();
public List<Window> Dialogos
{
     get { return _dialogos; }
     set { _dialogos = value; }
}
```

cada vez que abro uno nuevo lo agrego a ese array

```
private void FuncionEJemplo()
{
    CuadroDialogo x = new CuadroDialogo();
    Dialogos.Add(x);
    x.Show();
}
```

y en el evento Closing de la ventana que llama a los cuadros de diálogo (MainWindow) hago un ciclo for y cierro todos los cuadros de diálogo del array estático

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Dialogos.Count; i++)
    {
        Dialogos[i].Close();
    }
}
```

y eso hace que la apalicación se cierre sin cuadros abiertos.

Si solo quisiera que se cierren los cuadros de dialogo que fueron creados por una ventana en específico, hago que el array en vez de ser estático sea a nivel de clase, en la misma ventana y termino del mismo modo, con el evento `Closing` y el ciclo for.

Otra solución (parche) sería que en vez de abrir los dialogos con `Show()`, los abras con `ShowDialog()`, y eso hace que queden siempre encima de la ventana, así que no podrás cerrarla mientras no cierres el dialogo primero.

Comment: Esto es un poco rebuscado. De todas maneras, si quieres seguir usando un algoritmo similar, no es necesario que crees una lista de ventanas. Wpf ya la tiene, y puedes consultarla en `Application.Current.Windows`

Comment: La verdad no me he interiorizado en el uso de Current.Windows pero ahora que lo mencionas creo que lo haré, seguro salen cosas buenas.

Comment: Una cosa muy buena es que puedes filtrar por el tipo de ventanta, haciendo algo del tipo `Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Ventanta1>()` :)